# Javascript set method

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript "class", which looks like that:

```
function MapObject(x, y, size){
    var x = x;
    var y = y;
    var size = size;
    var color = "red";

    this.draw = function(g2d){
        g2d.setFillColor(color);
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
    }

    this.setColor = function(newColor){
        color = newColor;
    }

    this.collision = function(mousex, mousey){
        return mousex > x && mousex < x + size && mousey > y && mousey < y + size;
    }
}
```

My problem is, i want to name the paremeter in the "setColor" function "color", too. 
I know this from java:

```
void setColor(Color color){ this.color = color; }
```

Is there a way to achieve this in javascript?

I already tried:

```
this.setColor = function(color){
    this.color = color;
}
```

That does not work.
I dont get any error, but the value isnt changing..

Comment: simply pass the color name to function and in function utilize it like.color=yourFunctionArgument

Comment: @MuhammadAli: He is. Read the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your setup with local variables (i.e. `var color`) then **no**, you can't name the parameter `color`, since it shadows the outer variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the function which `color` variable you're amending. In your sample, `setColor` creates a new private variable of that function, and assigns the value of `newColor` to it. You should prepend the `this` keyword to the assignment operator within the `setColor()` function:

```
this.setColor = function(color){
    this.color = color;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2a87412w/)

You'll need to update your `draw()` function too, if you wish to use the object property:

```
this.draw = function(g2d){
    g2d.setFillColor(this.color);
    g2d.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
}
```

Comment: Uhm, it definitely is... http://jsfiddle.net/2a87412w/1/ Notice the `alert()` says `green`? And notice that's the color I specify on line 22?!